# Installed PyTorch CUDA (GPU) using Conda and returns False when typing 'torch.cuda.is_available()'

Tags: python, pytorch, anaconda

I installed PyTorch CUDA on a laptop which has NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Laptop GPU running on Windows 11 using `conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch` in the Anaconda Prompt. In order to check if it installed correctly into the Conda environment I opened up PyCharm and created a new project which used the Conda environment as the selected interpreter. I first typed in `import torch` in order to import PyTorch and then followed by `print(torch.cuda.is_available())` which printed out `False` . I would like to understand what is going wrong and whether there is any other way to check if it has installed correctly before I start my project.

The list of packages in the Conda environment are below which I got by doing the `conda list` command in the Anaconda Prompt. Any assistance on this would be much appreciated.

The packages are:

```
# packages in environment:
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
albumentations            1.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
anyio                     3.5.0            py38haa95532_0
appdirs                   1.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
argon2-cffi               21.3.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
argon2-cffi-bindings      21.2.0           py38h2bbff1b_0
asttokens                 2.0.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
attrs                     22.1.0           py38haa95532_0
backcall                  0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
beautifulsoup4            4.11.1           py38haa95532_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bleach                    4.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
blosc                     1.21.3               h6c2663c_0
bokeh                     3.1.0            py38hd4e2768_0
bottleneck                1.3.5            py38h080aedc_0
brotli                    1.0.9                h2bbff1b_7
brotli-bin                1.0.9                h2bbff1b_7
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py38h2bbff1b_1003
bzip2                     1.0.8                he774522_0
ca-certificates           2023.01.10           haa95532_0
certifi                   2022.12.7        py38haa95532_0
cffi                      1.15.1           py38h2bbff1b_3
cfitsio                   3.470                h2bbff1b_7
charls                    2.2.0                h6c2663c_0
charset-normalizer        2.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
cloudpickle               2.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
colorama                  0.4.6            py38haa95532_0
comm                      0.1.2            py38haa95532_0
contourpy                 1.0.5            py38h59b6b97_0
cryptography              39.0.1           py38h21b164f_0
cudatoolkit               10.2.89              h74a9793_1
cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
cytoolz                   0.12.0           py38h2bbff1b_0
dask-core                 2022.7.0         py38haa95532_0
debugpy                   1.5.1            py38hd77b12b_0
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
eigen                     3.3.7                h59b6b97_1
entrypoints               0.4              py38haa95532_0
executing                 0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
filelock                  3.9.0            py38haa95532_0
flit-core                 3.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
fonttools                 4.25.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
freetype                  2.12.1               ha860e81_0
fsspec                    2022.11.0        py38haa95532_0
giflib                    5.2.1                h8cc25b3_3
glib                      2.69.1               h5dc1a3c_2
gst-plugins-base          1.18.5               h9e645db_0
gstreamer                 1.18.5               hd78058f_0
hdf5                      1.12.1               h1756f20_2
icc_rt                    2022.1.0             h6049295_2
icu                       58.2                 ha925a31_3
idna                      3.4              py38haa95532_0
imagecodecs               2021.8.26        py38h319e4f4_2
imageio                   2.26.0           py38haa95532_0
importlib_resources       5.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
intel-openmp              2021.4.0          haa95532_3556
ipykernel                 6.19.2           py38hd4e2768_0
ipython                   8.10.0           py38haa95532_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
ipywidgets                7.6.5              pyhd3eb1b0_1
jedi                      0.18.1           py38haa95532_1
jinja2                    3.1.2            py38haa95532_0
joblib                    1.1.1            py38haa95532_0
jpeg                      9e                   h2bbff1b_1
jsonschema                4.17.3           py38haa95532_0
jupyter_client            7.4.9            py38haa95532_0
jupyter_core              5.2.0            py38haa95532_0
jupyter_server            1.23.4           py38haa95532_0
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2                      py_0
jupyterlab_widgets        3.0.5            py38haa95532_0
jxrlib                    1.1                  he774522_2
kiwisolver                1.4.4            py38hd77b12b_0
lcms2                     2.12                 h83e58a3_0
lerc                      3.0                  hd77b12b_0
libaec                    1.0.4                h33f27b4_1
libbrotlicommon           1.0.9                h2bbff1b_7
libbrotlidec              1.0.9                h2bbff1b_7
libbrotlienc              1.0.9                h2bbff1b_7
libclang                  12.0.0          default_h627e005_2
libdeflate                1.17                 h2bbff1b_0
libffi                    3.4.2                hd77b12b_6
libiconv                  1.16                 h2bbff1b_2
libogg                    1.3.5                h2bbff1b_1
libpng                    1.6.39               h8cc25b3_0
libprotobuf               3.20.3               h23ce68f_0
libsodium                 1.0.18               h62dcd97_0
libtiff                   4.5.0                h6c2663c_2
libuv                     1.44.2               h2bbff1b_0
libvorbis                 1.3.7                he774522_0
libwebp                   1.2.4                hbc33d0d_1
libwebp-base              1.2.4                h2bbff1b_1
libxml2                   2.9.14               h0ad7f3c_0
libxslt                   1.1.35               h2bbff1b_0
libzopfli                 1.0.3                ha925a31_0
locket                    1.0.0            py38haa95532_0
lxml                      4.9.1            py38h1985fb9_0
lz4-c                     1.9.4                h2bbff1b_0
markupsafe                2.1.1            py38h2bbff1b_0
matplotlib                3.7.1            py38haa95532_0
matplotlib-base           3.7.1            py38hf11a4ad_0
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6            py38haa95532_0
mistune                   0.8.4           py38he774522_1000
mkl                       2021.4.0           haa95532_640
mkl-service               2.4.0            py38h2bbff1b_0
mkl_fft                   1.3.1            py38h277e83a_0
mkl_random                1.2.2            py38hf11a4ad_0
mpmath                    1.2.1            py38haa95532_0
munkres                   1.1.4                      py_0
nbclassic                 0.5.2            py38haa95532_0
nbclient                  0.5.13           py38haa95532_0
nbconvert                 6.5.4            py38haa95532_0
nbformat                  5.7.0            py38haa95532_0
nest-asyncio              1.5.6            py38haa95532_0
networkx                  2.8.4            py38haa95532_1
notebook                  6.5.2            py38haa95532_0
notebook-shim             0.2.2            py38haa95532_0
numexpr                   2.8.4            py38h5b0cc5e_0
numpy                     1.23.5           py38h3b20f71_0
numpy-base                1.23.5           py38h4da318b_0
opencv                    4.6.0            py38h104de81_2
opencv-contrib-python     4.7.0.72                 pypi_0    pypi
openjpeg                  2.4.0                h4fc8c34_0
openssl                   1.1.1t               h2bbff1b_0
packaging                 23.0             py38haa95532_0
pandas                    1.5.3            py38hf11a4ad_0
pandocfilters             1.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
partd                     1.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
pcre                      8.45                 hd77b12b_0
pickleshare               0.7.5           pyhd3eb1b0_1003
pillow                    9.4.0            py38hd77b12b_0
pip                       23.0.1           py38haa95532_0
pkgutil-resolve-name      1.3.10           py38haa95532_0
platformdirs              2.5.2            py38haa95532_0
ply                       3.11                     py38_0
pooch                     1.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
prometheus_client         0.14.1           py38haa95532_0
prompt-toolkit            3.0.36           py38haa95532_0
psutil                    5.9.0            py38h2bbff1b_0
pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pygments                  2.11.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyopenssl                 23.0.0           py38haa95532_0
pyparsing                 3.0.9            py38haa95532_0
pyqt                      5.15.7           py38hd77b12b_0
pyqt5-sip                 12.11.0          py38hd77b12b_0
pyrsistent                0.18.0           py38h196d8e1_0
pysocks                   1.7.1            py38haa95532_0
python                    3.8.16               h6244533_3
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-fastjsonschema     2.16.2           py38haa95532_0
pytorch                   2.0.0               py3.8_cpu_0    pytorch
pytorch-mutex             1.0                         cpu    pytorch
pytz                      2022.7           py38haa95532_0
pywavelets                1.4.1            py38h2bbff1b_0
pywin32                   305              py38h2bbff1b_0
pywinpty                  2.0.10           py38h5da7b33_0
pyyaml                    6.0              py38h2bbff1b_1
pyzmq                     23.2.0           py38hd77b12b_0
qt-main                   5.15.2               he8e5bd7_7
qt-webengine              5.15.9               hb9a9bb5_5
qtwebkit                  5.212                h3ad3cdb_4
qudida                    0.0.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
requests                  2.28.1           py38haa95532_1
scikit-image              0.19.3           py38hd77b12b_1
scikit-learn              1.2.1            py38hd77b12b_0
scipy                     1.10.0           py38h321e85e_1
send2trash                1.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
setuptools                65.6.3           py38haa95532_0
sip                       6.6.2            py38hd77b12b_0
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1
snappy                    1.1.9                h6c2663c_0
sniffio                   1.2.0            py38haa95532_1
soupsieve                 2.3.2.post1      py38haa95532_0
sqlite                    3.41.1               h2bbff1b_0
stack_data                0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sympy                     1.11.1           py38haa95532_0
terminado                 0.17.1           py38haa95532_0
threadpoolctl             2.2.0              pyh0d69192_0
tifffile                  2021.7.2           pyhd3eb1b0_2
tinycss2                  1.2.1            py38haa95532_0
tk                        8.6.12               h2bbff1b_0
toml                      0.10.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
toolz                     0.12.0           py38haa95532_0
torchvision               0.15.0                 py38_cpu    pytorch
tornado                   6.2              py38h2bbff1b_0
tqdm                      4.64.1           py38haa95532_0
traitlets                 5.7.1            py38haa95532_0
typing-extensions         4.4.0            py38haa95532_0
typing_extensions         4.4.0            py38haa95532_0
urllib3                   1.26.14          py38haa95532_0
vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1
vs2015_runtime            14.27.29016          h5e58377_2
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
webencodings              0.5.1                    py38_1
websocket-client          0.58.0           py38haa95532_4
wheel                     0.38.4           py38haa95532_0
widgetsnbextension        3.5.2            py38haa95532_0
win_inet_pton             1.1.0            py38haa95532_0
wincertstore              0.2              py38haa95532_2
winpty                    0.4.3                         4
xyzservices               2022.9.0         py38haa95532_1
xz                        5.2.10               h8cc25b3_1
yaml                      0.2.5                he774522_0
zeromq                    4.3.4                hd77b12b_0
zfp                       0.5.5                hd77b12b_6
zipp                      3.11.0           py38haa95532_0
zlib                      1.2.13               h8cc25b3_0
zstd                      1.5.2                h19a0ad4_0
```

Installed PyTorch CUDA using `conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch` in the Anaconda Prompt in my Conda environment. It finished installing and then, in PyCharm, typed in the `print(torch.cuda.is_available())` in the PyCharm IDE after selecting the Conda environment as the interpreter.

**UPDATE:** As requested by a person who commented I have also run `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.7 -c pytorch -c nvidia`. The issue still appears to be happening where 'False' is being outputted in my Python script which checks if Cuda is available.

Comment: Follow the official Pytorch instructions to get Pytorch through conda, see https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Holt - thanks for your comment. Just to confirm I have already read the official PyTorch instructions.

Comment: @AnealB If you did read you did not follow them. The conda instruction in your question is not the one from the official Pytorch documentation.

Comment: @Holt - I can confirm I tried 'conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.7 -c pytorch -c nvidia' but even after it's installed successfully and restarted PyCharm it still comes out as False.

Comment: @AnealB Then update your question. If you ran this after the command in your question, then the second command probably did not do anything, you need to uninstall what  you previously installed before running it, or start with a clean environment.

Comment: @Holt - ok I will try installing with a clean environment however previously did run this first previously and it failed whilst installing. Thanks.